# Select rows with GROUP BY excluding GROUP with flag ( MySQL )

Tags: mysql, group-by

Having this table with 3 columns:

```
id    name    flag
1       A       1 
2       A       0
3       A       0
4       B       0
5       B       0
6       C       0
7       D       1
```

I want to select all groups that does not have flag = 1

Expected results:

```
name
B
C
```

this is not working because ( correctly ) include all groups that has at list one

```
SELECT name
FROM test 
WHERE flag <> '1'
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation is one way to do this, but you need a `HAVING` clause to assert that a matching group has no flag = 1:

```
SELECT name
FROM test
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(flag = 1) = 0;
```

### Demo

You could also use a subquery with exists logic:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM test t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t2.flag = 1);
```

Comment: why not HAVING SUM(flag) = 0 ?

Comment: Why not indeed, that would also work, but it is by coincidence, and most the time, it would not work (hence I did not think to write it that way).

Comment: Ok Thanks, was just to better understand how it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get the desired output.

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM `test` 
WHERE `name` <> ALL ( SELECT `name` FROM `test` WHERE `flag` = 1 )
GROUP BY `name`;
```

Comment: This query return duplicate for name field

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `name`
FROM `test`
WHERE `name` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `test` WHERE `flag` = 1);
```